# compare two times in format 'hh:mm tt' in javascript not work in safari

Tags: javascript, safari

I want to compare two times

```
 compareTwoTime('06:10 PM', '07:10 PM',false)



function compareTwoTime(startTime, stopTime, moreAndEqual) {
            var t = new Date();
            d = t.getDate();
            m = t.getMonth() + 1;
            y = t.getFullYear();

            //Convert time into date object
            var d1 = new Date(m + " " + d + " " + y + " " + startTime);
            var d2 = new Date(m + " " + d + " " + y + " " + stopTime);

            //Get timestamp
            var t1 = d1.getTime();
            var t2 = d2.getTime();

            if (moreAndEqual)
                return t1 >= t2;
            else
                return t1 < t2;
        }
```

in chrome it work ok, but in safari

```
`new Date(m + " " + d + " " + y + " " + startTime); is NaN`
```

some proposal?

Answer (score 0):

Dates are always tricky. If you can afford it and you do a lot of date manipulations in your app, I would simply use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Otherwise, you could do some string manipulation and put the AM/PM to the front of string, and then compare the two lexicographically.